# Is there a way to use wildcards when downloading and saving a file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, url, download, wildcard, webclient

I have a `PowerShell` script that I am using to download a file from a URL every morning, however it has started putting the date on it every day, therefore making it imppossible to use a scheduled `PowerShell` everyday to download it.

Is there anyway to use a wildcard to make it pick up all of the dates?

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile("https://test.com/store/scheduled/320%2019.10.22.csv","\\server\shared\Reports\RawData\Cross Selling Data.csv")
```

The bold bit is what I am looking to Wildcard after '320' as this is the report number but before .csv. I've tried * but that doesn't seem to work. The date obviously changes on each day's report.

Comment: *"therefore making it imppossible to use a scheduled PowerShell everyday to download it"* Not really, if it always is the current date, you can add that date to the URL before downloading.

Comment: Also, for downloading files, you can use the native `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet, you don't have to resort to .NET methods for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to using **wildcard**, the answer is **no**. It's impossible to use wildcard while making web requests as it'd require checking every possible path.

What is possible is to construct the path programmatically if you know the pattern. For example, in your case

```bsh
# That input
PS> Get-Date -Format 'yy.MM.dd'
# Gives you the following result
19.10.22
```

which looks similarly to the pattern you included in your code (I assume `%20` is space). To use it in string (assuming you use double quotes `"`) you can use the following:

```
"https://test.com/store/scheduled/320%20$(Get-Date -Format 'yy.MM.dd').csv"
```

Last, but not least, as [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) mentioned in comments, [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) might work for you as well.